# Border end caps not rounding on some shapes in Sketch App?

Tags: sketch-app, illustration

I have been having trouble with border end caps not wanting to round up properly. I can't seem to find much about this issue, so I wonder if I'm just doing something wrong.

I start out with a normal shape, for example a rounded rectangle. I hide the fill and give it a border of 6px. I then use the scissors to cut something out and set the end cap to rounded.

As you can see, some shapes will round and others won't. Why? Is it the rounded shapes of 2 and 3? Is this a bug and is there a workaround?

[image]

What the path looks like:
[image]

And the shape is just about as basic as can be. No clipping or anything:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that some of those strokes aren't actually strokes, rather they are shapes? (like illustrator's outline stroke feature)

Comment: @WELZ they are all made in the same way, shape > hide fill > show border. Only difference is that 2 and 3 were made using an oval and 1 and 4 were made using a rounded rectangle.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue (in Illustrator - as that's what I have) trying all the possible causes that I could think of, however I was unsuccessful at recreating the problem, it may just be a sketch flaw.

Comment: can you show us what the paths look like? meaning if you double-click them  as if to edit the vectors?

Comment: Is there a clipping path?

Comment: It may have something to do with the method that you are using to *cut* it (Scissors).

Comment: @joojaa no! And I've added a screenshot of the path.

Comment: @spiral added the screenshot!

Comment: Could it have something to do with you strokes being aligned to outside?

Comment: Yes, I suspect the same thing as @WELZ

Comment: @WELZ No, they are on the inside, I left them to the default setting.I then use the cogwheel to select rounded ends.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 that's what I meant, could that cause the problem?

Comment: @WELZ Ah sorry. If I put the stroke outside the end cap gets even weirder, kind of curled inwards.

Comment: What if you put the stroke *on* the path

Comment: Dumb question but do you have rounded joints selected as well?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx2zE.png

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I tried with and without rounded joints but that does absolutely nothing for the oval shapes sadly. Should it help? Maybe it is a bug after all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your **border position** to **center** at the begining of the editing (later it will not be possible) :
[image: set border to center]

You can also add a new border - it will automatically be set to "Center" and won't cause any issue.

Comment: I tried it and that's the answer. If the border position is set as anything other than Center it will cause the issues described in the question, and it's not possible to change that after using the Scissors tool.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem. Solved it by clicking the small slice icon in the "Presets" menu. Then you can enlarge the area thats been exported, i.e. add a padding to your image so that the border isn't cut out.

[image: Sketch 55.2 export detail]

Happy editing!

Comment: That's not what's being asked